# What is the equivalent cpp function for tf.train.import_meta_graph() in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I need to know the equivalent C++ function for https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph

Can anyone please help with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent of [`tf.train.import_meta_graph()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/import_meta_graph) in C++, because its main role is to set up Python data structures that are useful in interpreting the low-level `GraphDef` that the MetaGraph contains.

There are a couple of related functions that might be useful, however:

- In the C API, `TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel()` will import a "SavedModel" file, which contains one or more meta graphs, and instantiate a session using it. You can create a saved model in Python using the [`tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/builder/SavedModelBuilder) class. See the [SavedModel documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/saved_model/README.md) for more details.
- In the C++ API, the [`tensorflow::LoadSavedModel()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/93547a1bafa8c8f5d5fc428fa33cadb6eae865a5/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.h#L46) function serves a similar role.